# How may I get the ceiling score (score and member) from a SortedSet in Redis?

Tags: redis, sortedset

**In Redis, I want to get the ceiling score (and member) for a score that is not in the SortedSet.**

In Java, there is [NavigableSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) and we may use [E ceiling(E e)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#ceiling-E-) in order to *return the least element in this set greater than or equal to the given element, or null if there is no such element*.

Is there any way to do the same in Redis, maybe using SortedSets or other data structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) with a Lua script. Imagine the following sorted set:

```
zadd test 1 a
zadd test 2 b
zadd test 4 c
```

You have 3 elements with scores 1, 2, 4 and you'd like to call `ceiling(3)`. Save the following Lua script as `script.lua`:

```lua
local key = KEYS[1]
local givenScore = tonumber(ARGV[1])
local scores = redis.call("ZRANGEBYSCORE", key, givenScore, "+inf", "withscores", "limit", 0, 1)
if (scores == nil or #scores<2) then
    return nil
end
return tonumber(scores[2])
```

and call it with:

```bash
$ redis-cli eval "$(cat script.lua)" 1 test 3
```

Here are some sample runs with the above data set:

```bash
$ redis-cli eval "$(cat script.lua)" 1 test 2
(integer) 2
$ redis-cli eval "$(cat script.lua)" 1 test 3
(integer) 4
$ redis-cli eval "$(cat script.lua)" 1 test 4
(nil)
```

Comment: Thanks Duru, it is ok your script, but it is not suitable for my data. I have 13200000 keys. Getting the range from 1 to -1 and then ignoring almost everything is not possible. May I conclude that there is no `ceiling` or "scalable O(log n max) ceiling trick" for sorted sets in redis? If so, please edit your answer and I will accept it :) Thanks again :)

Comment: @Costin Now I get it. I've updated my answer with a more efficient solution. It's `O(log(n))`, so should fit your case :)

Comment: I use this for geolocation. Input data is a dictionary `range:value` : `ip1-ip2` : `location`. The IP is an int. I imagine one key corresponding to sorted set and keeping as scores the `ip2` and as members the `location`. If I ask for `ip2-1` I expect to get the same location as for `ip2` (assume ip1 is smaller that ip2). Just like the `NavigableSet.ceiling(key)` in Java :)

Comment: Sorry, it won't work. `zadd test 9 d`. Your solution will not answer for the score `6`. I cannot know the gap between scores, it may be `1` (consecutive scores), it may be huge.

Comment: Fixed. And it's still `O(log(n))` :)

Comment: Great! Thanks :) Imagine, that I've also used that solution this morning, but for other purpose :)) `jedis.zrevrangeByScore(REDIS_KEY_LAST_UPDATE, "+inf", "(0", 0, 1);`

Comment: You can reduce your answer to one line: `redis.call("ZRANGEBYSCORE", key, givenScore, "+inf", "withscores", "limit", 0, 1)`. This is the answer :)

Comment: Ah yes :) My original answer retrieved multiple rows from Redis, so the script was necessary, but now you can just skip Lua and call `ZRANGEBYSCORE` directly.